# Facebook-esque checkin in my app?

Tags: checkin

I'm sorry if this sounds like a novice question, but I am developing an app and I want users to be able to tag themselves at places like a Facebook check in. But I also want the ease of a Facebook check in - im not sure how it does it but it converts your geocoordinates to more meaningful user data e.g. names of bars, restaurants, hotels, streets, public places, where you can check in.

Is this some kind of library? Is it publicly available? Is there any way to do this on my app?

Thanks

Comment: I'm talking more about the library of places that people have created. Is it part of the Facebook API? or something from google maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering all three questions at once: When you check-in to a place that hasn't been tagged before, you create it (in facebook).

Besides that there is [open street map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=6/51.330/10.453) and [open point of interest databse](http://openpois.net/).

Facebook does not simply share their database.

The only thing you can do is get authorized by the user and load the users places, using the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api) and the [check-in method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/checkin).